# Struts 2 dispatcher

Tags: struts2, dispatcher

i would like to initialize (in Struts2) a property(data loading from a file) only once and make available that property for entire struts 2 application.
how can i achieve that? do i need override struts 2 dispatcher?

Regards
Raju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `ServletContextListener` defined in `web.xml` that opens your property file and sets the desired value to the `ServletContext` via:

```
getServletContext().setAttribute("dataKey", dataValue);
```

The `ServletContext` has application-wide scope.

**Update:**

You can create a new class that implements `ServletContextListener` (here is its JavaDoc: [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)), which requires that you define `contextInitialized()` and `contextDestroyed()` methods.

The method `contextInitialized()` is called right before your servlet begins accepting requests.  In your `contextInitialized()` method, you would include the `getServletContext().setAttribute("dataKey", dataValue)` call.

In order to register your listener, you will need to add a listener definition in your `web.xml` file:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>CLASS_PATH.CLASS_NAME</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You'll need to replace CLASS_PATH.CLASS_NAME in the above XML with the class path and name of the context listener class you just created.

Comment: thanks for your reply...i am using Struts 2..how do i do that....i have to override struts2 dispatcher right....

Comment: I provided more detail instructions on how to implement a ServletContextListener.  Please let me know if you have trouble with my directions.